# Android library: Class file not found when "implementation project" is used for module dependency of a library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-library

I'm working in a project that has 3 modules as shown below:

```
Project
|
|-- Common 
|
|-- SDK
|
|-- App
```

`Common` is an Android library module that all the other modules depend on but I do not have to publish it anywhere because it contains only common code for the other modules. On the other hand `SDK` is another Android library project which has to be published on our internal artifactory.

`App` is a sample project of the SDK. I'm able to publish the `SDK` artifact with no problems but when I import it in a client application the compilation fails because none of the classes from the `Common` module are found.

For the third party dependencies that the SDK module depends on I use `implementation` (e.g. `implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'` and all those dependencies are successfully added to the `SDK` POM file) and for the dependency on the `Common` module I use `implementation project(path: ':Common')`.

In the client application that imports the `SDK` library the compiler shows  the following error

```
Error: cannot access Foo
class file for com.acme.Foo not found
```

(Foo is a class in the Common module)

Why when I import the `SDK` none of the classes from the `Common` module are found? What I expect is the compiler to merge the two modules into a single one. Has anyone an idea about how I can solve this problem?

(I know a solution is to publish `Common` on the artifactory but I don't want to do that since this is only internal common code).

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project? maybe Invalidate cache and restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour for gradle modules; as you surmised, publishing each as a separate artefact (and listing the dependencies in the pom file) is the only supported usage.

There is a plugin that may do what you need at https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar , but it's no longer maintained so your mileage may vary.
Alternatively, you may achieve similar results by updating your SDK sourceSets to point directly at the common module sources, and remove the gradle dependency entirely. Can't find a good link for this, but it should be possible. This does remove all the built-in handling of modules, but may better match how you're using the module.

Answer (score 11):

Repleace `implementation project(path: ':Common')` by `api project(path: ':Common')`
About difference between api and implementation you can check [this article](https://medium.com/mindorks/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa).

Comment: It does not solve the problem, I still get the same error 

Comment: Please share your all modules build.gradle files

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue myself.

A visual help is to use `Android Studio` its own project structure view: [image]

> File -> Project Structure

Then for your `:app` you can check what `modules dependencies` you have:

[image]

If you need to, you can remove the current module dependencies and add them again just to double check. After that when you click "OK" gradle will try to sync its files.

This way you are letting Android Studio do the work of integrating all the modules, and hopefully, it will fix your issue.

---

**PS:** I believe that you are importing your project in the wrong way. You should use `api` instead of `implementation`. From the documentation:

> **api:** When a module includes an api dependency, it's letting Gradle
>   know that the module wants to transitively export that dependency to
>   other modules, so that it's available to them at both runtime and
>   compile time. This configuration behaves just like compile (which is
>   now deprecated), and you should typically use this only in library
>   modules. That's because, if an api dependency changes its external
>   API, Gradle recompiles all modules that have access to that dependency
>   at compile time. So, having a large number of api dependencies can
>   significantly increase build times. Unless you want to expose a
>   dependency's API to a separate test module, app modules should instead
>   use implementation dependencies.

Check the official docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations

Comment: @DiegoPalomar does this fix your issue?

Comment: The "api" instead of "implementation" quote fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The most voted up answer from André Sousa is correct but it only helps if you don't use any of the dependencies in your library directly.

It's a common case that you have a 'Common' module which might import some common libraries (Joda DateTime, firebase, ...). In that case, **all such dependencies in the library need to be declared with 'api'** and not 'implementation'. This ensures that when your app imports your Common module, these classes are also available.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.

In my case, I have created a `kotlin` library and try to add with java project. So please make sure `kotlin` should be configured for library.

That works for me now.